# How do I add a wordpress notice message after page redirect?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

The following example will redirect all non-authenticated users to a custom 'signup' page when trying to visit the 'goodies' page.

however, I need to display a notification message on the signup page after redirect, What is the best way to do this?

```
function my_page_template_redirect() {
    if ( is_page( 'goodies' ) && ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
        wp_redirect( home_url( '/signup/' ) );
        die;
    }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'my_page_template_redirect' );
```

here is an example of the code that displays the message

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_init', 'pt_custom_notice' );

function pt_custom_notice() {
    wc_add_notice( 'This is a Error notice', 'error' );

}
```